# Core Data fetching many-to-one relationship objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In my app I have two entities which are `Items` and `Lists`. Each item belongs to only one list and each list has many items. Thus in the modal the entities has the following relationships:

1. For `Items`: to-one relationship (`belongs_to_list`) pointing to one list
2. For `Lists`: to-many relationship (`has_items`) pointing to many items

How can I fetch the items using a predicate to check whether the list it's related to is equal to a specific list I provide? I don't want to fetch the items through the list (like fetching objects of `has_items`). I want to be able to use `belongs_to_list` in a predicate to compare it to a managed object I have. I tried the following but it's not working. Any help please?

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Items" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"item_detail" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"list.list_name == %@", [self.currentList valueForKey:@"list_name"]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well your question, the following predicates would be correct:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"belongs_to_list == %@", [self currentList]];
```

Let me know if this does work for you.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. when i add this predicate while it's nil it fetches everything and when i assign the current list the app crashes.

Comment: @user2176995 Could you share the crash log?

Comment: t's not printing anything i the crash log. anyway i stopped using NSFetchResultsController. i'm using the normal way which is working fine now.

Comment: @user2176995 Ok. Don't forget to mark as answered if my answer helped you. Or just upvote. Cheers.